# Creating separate links using ID classes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

This Wordpress template I'm working with has a section where it places six icons which display tooltips when hovered over. I need them to become links to different pages but I only really know CSS and basic HTML as I'm primarily a designer.

I've found the appropriate PHP file and managed to insert a link to Google as a placeholder but it makes them all link to there. I'm guessing from the code that it's using PHP to 'ask' for which icon to insert and then getting them from elsewhere, Jquery maybe? I barely even know what Jquery is.

Anyway, here's the code:

[image]

You can see where I've added the `<a href="http://www.google.com">` for the

```
<span class="feature-icon feature">
<i class="<?php echo $icon; ?>"></i>
</span>
```

Any idea how I can get them to link to separate URLs?

Comment: please provide us a bigger piece of the code of your template

Comment: The whole file is here: http://pastebin.com/m4XaBhd4

Answer (score 0):

Editing this php file is not really good approach.
These six icons are editable on WP admin page as a custom post type. You need to extend this post type with a link option.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by custom post type? The only options I get when editing the services in the admin dashboard is changing the icon from a selection and adding things to the tooltips that appear when you hover over each icon. Here is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/A4ny35N

Comment: I am sorry, I was wrong, these icons are not defined as custom type, but as a meta options. Could you please upload your whole template somewhere? I need piece of code, where meta options are defined (maybe in functions.php, but it depends...) and we need to add another fields for links

Comment: It's not my theme, it's one I bought. Not sure how to go about that?

Comment: Without the template I am just guessing. BTW I was not wrong in previous comments. Custom post type was used. Try to find a piece of code with "register_post_type" (maybe in funtions.php, but it could be anywhere, it is the point where services post type was defined, we need to alter it and add link option). You can find more about custom post types here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: I'm not sure I should be uploading paid themes (illegal distribution?) but I can post up a few files which may be relevant? Here they are: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3rgc1uii7g7drkq/RzTHCMJL7K

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatelly non of them is helping. You need to upload file, where is register_post_type function used (it could be in different directory like framework/php) I do not know it depends on the author of the template. Try to use Find function and search for "register_post_type". Also, most of authors of paid themes provide support for their customers, try to contact him.

Comment: I found this in framework/php/, it looks promising to my naive eye. Any good? http://pastebin.com/z06UZzkr

Comment: Yes, this is what we need. I have a question to be sure. Links, you want to add should be external(like google, you used in example) or internal(going to the detail page of service after clicking)?

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about external link make this(but before doing anything BACK UP your code and database):
find:

```
"features" =>
 array(
```

And add this code right above it:

```
"link" =>      
  array(
     "label"=>__("Link",'Pixelentity Theme/Plugin'),
     "type"=>"Text",
     "default"=>""
  ),
```

But I am still just guessing without whole template, so try it and let me know the result